# scroll the div to error position in jquery

Tags: scroll, focus

Need to focus the first error input field,then second if first is filled and so on......,but the code which i have written focus the last field first, may be i know what is the reason behind it but not able to find out the solution.....So many a thanks if u guys help me as i m new to programming.

```
function contactvalidate()
{
  var error=0;
    var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

if($.trim(firstname) =="")
    {
    $("#firstname + p").remove();
    error=error+1;
    $("#firstname").after("<p>Enter first name</p>");
    $("#firstname").focus();
    }
    else
    {
    $("#firstname + p").remove();
    }

    if($.trim(lastname) =="")
    {
    $("#lastname + p").remove();
    error=error+1;  
    $("#lastname").after("<p>Enter last name</p>");
    $("#lastname").focus();
    }
    else
    {
    $("#lastname + p").remove();
    }   

    if(email =="")
    {
    $("#email + p").remove();
    error=error+1;
    $("#email").after("<p>Enter email </p>");
    $("#email").focus();

    }

    else if (IsEmail(email)==false)
    {
        $("#email + p").remove();
    error=error+1;
    $("#email").after("<p>Enter Valid E-mail</p>");
    $("#email").focus();
    }

    else
    {
    $("#email + p").remove();
    }

    if (error==0)
    {
    return true;


    }
    else{

    return false;
    }

}
```

Here is the Html

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <div class="field_area">
               <label>First Name<span>*</span>:</label><input type="text" value="<?php echo $firstname ?> " name="firstname" id="firstname" ></input>
               </div>
               <div class="field_area">
               <label>Last Name<span>*</span>:</label><input type="text" value=" <?php echo $lastname ?>" name="lastname" id="lastname" ></input>
               </div>
               <div class="field_area">
               <label>Email<span>*</span>:</label><input type="text"  name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" id="email"></input><?php echo "<p>" . "$emailexit"."</p>"; ?>
               </div>

<div class="field_area">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit"  name="submit" onclick=" return contactvalidate();"></input>
               </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this but ur validation code is poor...
U need to stop the further execution of code after every .focus() hence return false else the execution continues...

```
   function contactvalidate()
    {
      var error=0;
        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

    if($.trim(firstname) =="")
        {
        $("#firstname + p").remove();
        error=error+1;
        $("#firstname").after("<p>Enter first name</p>");
        $("#firstname").focus();
     return false;
        }
        else
        {
        $("#firstname + p").remove();
        }

        if($.trim(lastname) =="")
        {
        $("#lastname + p").remove();
        error=error+1;  
        $("#lastname").after("<p>Enter last name</p>");
        $("#lastname").focus();
     return false;
        }
        else
        {
        $("#lastname + p").remove();
        }   

        if(email =="")
        {
        $("#email + p").remove();
        error=error+1;
        $("#email").after("<p>Enter email </p>");
        $("#email").focus();
     return false;

        }

        else if (IsEmail(email)==false)
        {
            $("#email + p").remove();
        error=error+1;
        $("#email").after("<p>Enter Valid E-mail</p>");
        $("#email").focus();
     return false;
        }

        else
        {
        $("#email + p").remove();
        }

        if (error==0)
        {
        return true;


        }
        else{

        return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,but Can u help me to write the better validation code. Want to show all the error on screen ,and keep the field on focus which is not filled,is it possible?

Comment: You mean to say show all the errors on screen but the focus should be on the first error field??

Comment: YES,need to show all error on the screen ,If first field is not filled than focus should be on first field  but  if it is filled than show the  focus on the field which is not filled and that too in squenece.Mean if 2nd and 3rd both are not filled than the focus should be on 2nd field. Possible?